# How to install Tensorflow 2.0 install with Conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, tensorflow2.0

I get this error when I try to run a test example.

> Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to >initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.

I have tried a recommended process for conda found [here](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-to-Install-TensorFlow-with-GPU-Support-on-Windows-10-Without-Installing-CUDA-UPDATED-1419/). Create new environment install Tensorflow-GPU. Install Jupyter Notebook and test some code. I have tried changing versions of cudatoolkit and cudnn but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. The install Tensorflow-GPU puts Cudatoolkit 10.0.130 and cudnn 7.6.

```
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_images.reshape(60000, 28, 28, 1)

test_images = test_images.reshape(10000, 28, 28, 1)

train_images, test_images = train_images/255, test_images/255

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape (28,28,1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

import time

start_time=time.time()

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=128, epochs=15, verbose=1,
     validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))

print('Training took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-start_time))
```

Comment: Ok so I tried to install Cudatoolkit 10.1 over the 10.0 version but it gives errors and wont actually install. When I tried to downgrade cudnn it wants to downgrade tensorflow from 2.0 to 1.14

Comment: I don't really have an answer for you, but your example code works for me - I also get cudatoolkit 10.0.130, cudnn 7.6.0, tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0, python 3.7.4. I use miniconda but that shouldn't matter. Are you running this inside a jupyter notebook or as script? Also are your Nvidia drivers up to date?

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of stack overflow community, posting solution here though it presented in GitHub.

You can add below code in the beginning of program, will resolve your issue

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```

For more details please refer this [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24828) thread.